# I don’t really get the meaning of the first part of the comment

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> **Funny but sad, how much do parents who are handy with their hands miss
>   out on.** If you are gifted with children, you have to accept the breaks
>   and burns as well. At least you left your mark on your home.

https://www.quora.com/What-did-you-do-as-a-child-that-you-hid-from-your-parents/answer/Chris-Hawkes-11?share=2f5c077e&srid=hnyk7